# Grouped overview of total lines in Reporting Service

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I've created a report using Reporting Services. I have a large set of data that I group by countries, that I have split up using the "Group" function and setting a PageBreak between every different country. I then added a total so I get total lines on the bottom of every page.

Now my questions is: Is it possible to create an overview page that displays only the "Total" lines for every country on one sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a rectangle with a page break below the tablix that shows details and totals on the bottom. Now add another tablix grouped by Country and use this expression:

```
=Sum(Fields!Value.Value,"Country")
```

This is the dataset I used as example:

[image]

With this tablix and settings:

[image]

It previews something like this:

[image]

Let me know if this can help you.

Comment: Thanks so much, the perfect answer to my question!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding a new table, which references the same dataset, and just show the total values.

For example, create a new Tablix, Group the rows on Country, and set the data value to be

```
=sum(Fields!mySum.Value)
```

This example shows the detail as you describe with a table showing the individual rows and a total row, and then the tablix below shows the new table you need to create which just shows the summaries.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a toggle to create an totals overview. Don't know if it's applicable in your situation but I thought it was worth mentioning.

Looks like this:

[image]

[image]

The dataset is same as the one from Jonus, but you have to add a parent group for the details and just use =sum(Fields!Value.Value) as shown in the picture.

[image]

The settings for visibility of the details group are the following:

[image]

Hope this helps :)